# Is there a definite integral that evaluates to the constant $e$?

Tags: integration

The integrand should not involve the constant $e$ itself nor, preferably, $\cosh$, $\sinh$, etc. $\pi$ arises in definite integrals such as
$$\int_0^a \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

The integrand must be an algebraic function with rational coefficients, and the limits of integration must be rational. (Thank you Woodface for the suggestion.)

Comment: How about $\int_0^e 1dx$?

Comment: "Obvious" is vague; every connection is obvious after it's made and explained. I suggest to make the question more precise: the integrand must be an algebraic function with rational coefficients, and the limits of integration must be rational.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$e$ is not a period i.e. not a number that can be represented by the integral of a rational or irrational function over a domain defined by rational functions. The periods form a subring of $\mathbb{C}$. There is a very good article by D. Zagier and M.Kontsevitch on periods. Don't have the reference but Google should help

Comment: I believe [this](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/kontzagi.pdf) is the article in question.

Comment: Yes @Unochiii that is it

Comment: Very nice reference! However, according to sec. 1.1, it is only *conjectured* that $e$ is not a period.

Comment: It is a very active research area. I understand Kontsevitch has proven $e$ is not a period but I have no reference for that

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{-\infty}^1 \sum_{k=0}^\infty {1 \over k!}t^k dt$

Comment: It seems obviously connected to $e$.

Comment: Picky. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: What I am looking for, ideally, is something not to involve infinite series, of even infinite as the integration limit.  An integrand that will represent an area easy to visualize, and preferably not going to infinite.  My apologies, for not specifying this above.

Comment: Interesting question! The log, in the sense you describe, is "natural," and it is therefore not surprising that it was discovered first.

Answer (score 0):

Not visualizable as an area, but
$$
2^{\int_{0}^{1}2^x dx}
$$
is nice.

Comment: ...but $2^x=e^{x\log2}$, no?